# When to use artist-mode, and when to use picture-mode

Tags: artist-mode, picture-mode

Why does emacs offer two drawing modes?

> artist mode
>
> picture mode

Are they competing packages or have different use cases.

What I tried: googled "emacs artist-mode versus picture-mode"

My setup: `emacsclient -nw` in `Terminal.app`

UPDATE: Found the answer to my own question. Artist mode is more "user friendly" specially if you don't mind using the mouse. If you're running in -nw console mode, artist-mode might not work, printing ansi escape codes (thats what happened to me). It might have something to do with my `M-! echo $SHELL` having the value "dumb"

Comment: What did the doc strings tell you? What part of the difference is unclear to you?

Comment: Technically it seems like the Terminal should not be printing ansi escape codes, especially because when I open emacs in GUI, make a drawing, save and then reopen in the terminal version with `emacs -nw` I get to view the drawing. It would be of great interest to me to get artist-mode (or maybe picture mode) working in the terminal. (now it prints nothing expect those escape codes) I'm using iTerm btw.